# Compile-time assertions with GHC Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, compile-time

Coming from C++, I'm used to be able to build simple forms of compile-time assertions, where I could emit warnings or errors during compilation if some simple conditions (e.g. over simple algebraic expressions) weren't met via use of template meta-programming and/or `cpp(1)`

For instance, if I wanted to make sure my program compiles only when `Int` has at least a certain `minBound`/`maxBound` range or alternatively, if a loss-free (as in reversible) conversion from `Int64` to `Int` is possible with the current compilation target. Is this possible with some GHC Haskell extension? My first guess would have been to use TH. Are there other GHC facilities that could be exploited to this end?

Comment: (Un)fortunately, there are no dependent types in Haskell, which would have been great for this purpose (but which would likely require you put many more type annotations).

Comment: @Alexandre: Sounds interesting... Could you elaborate on how dependent types could be used to, say, determine whether `Int64` fits into an `Int` at compile-time?

Comment: Dependent types encode a full blown theorem prover into the type system. Any property of data can be expressed in its type.

Comment: @hvr: you can use an `Int lo hi` type when `lo` and `hi` are bounds on the integer. Now, eg. `(+)` has type `Int l1 h1 -> Int l2 h2 -> Int (l1 + l2) (h1 + h2)`.

Comment: For the `minBound/maxBound` check you can also use a `configure` script.

Comment: I don't know if you can use it for this purpose, but GHC allows you to run the C preprocessor over your Haskell code with the `-XCPP` flag (or `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` directive).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a generalized and slightly simplified version of [Anthony's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648764/compile-time-assertions-with-ghc-haskell/6654286#6654286):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module StaticAssert (staticAssert) where

import Control.Monad (unless)
import Language.Haskell.TH (report)

staticAssert cond mesg = do
    unless cond $ report True $ "Compile time assertion failed: " ++ mesg
    return [] -- No need to make a dummy declaration
```

Usage:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import StaticAssert

$(staticAssert False "Not enough waffles")
```

Comment: This is indeed a refinement of my noodling around with TH!

Comment: Thanks to you both, @hammar and @Anthony. The required TH-voodoo looks easier than I expected :-)... btw, why do you use the `$( .. )` syntax? isn't that optional for top-level TH invocations?

Comment: @hvr: Yes, though I like to use it anyway to make it easier to mentally separate the TH from normal code.

Comment: Even if it's optional, it's *way* clearer to use the splice syntax uniformly.

Comment: @Carl makes a very good point. Haskell's macro culture is still nascent, so we need to tread lightly to avoid brutalizing what prettiness we currently have.

Answer (score 6):

Using TH for this isn't too bad. Here is a module that defines the desired assertion as part of a vestigial declaration:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module CompileTimeWarning where
import Control.Monad (unless)
import Data.Int (Int64)
import Language.Haskell.TH

assertInt = let test = fromIntegral (maxBound::Int) == (maxBound::Int64)
            in do unless test $ report True "Int is not safe!"
                  n <- newName "assertion"
                  e <- fmap NormalB [|()|]
                  return $ [FunD n [Clause [] e []]]
```

Using the assertion involves a top-level declaration that isn't used for anything other than the assertion:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import CompileTimeWarning
$(assertInt)
```